# SIGINT propagation for background process vs for subshell

Tags: bash, subprocess, background-process, subshell

I have two programs in two files that I run with bash:

The first:

```
(sleep 100) &
wait
```

The second:

```
sleep 100 &
wait
```

If I send a SIGINT to the first program, it also kills my sleep command. But for the second the sleep command remains and isn't killed.

Why the difference?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Since you haven't received an answer here, you might try posting it on [unix.se].